# Javascript output error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am having trouble outputing text to a div in Javascript. When I call the function on button click it displays the text for a fraction of second and then disappears. Why is it so? The code is given below;

**Code:**

```
function val(){
        var x = document.getElementById('us').value
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <br />
   <input type="text" id="us" name="username"></input>
   <br />           
   <button type="submit" onclick="val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i made a few changes from your code try this one http://jsfiddle.net/b19u9q4k/

Comment: thats because of submit.

Comment: and if you are not using submit, then remove that method="post" attribute, because you are not submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a submit button in a form, its default action is to submit the form that is why the result is disappearing(the page is getting refreshed).

Since you really don't want to submit the form(here you are just doing some dynamic changes to the page), one easy solution is to change the type of the button to `button`

```js
function val() {
  var x = document.getElementById('us').value
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="us" name="username"></input>
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Another solution is to prevent the default action of the submit button click by returning false

Answer (score 4):

```
<form method="post">
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <br />
   <input type="text" id="us" name="username"></input>
   <br />           
   <button type="button" id="asd">Sign Up</button>
</form>

$('#asd').click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById('us').value
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

});
```

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b19u9q4k/)***

I made a few changes. I changed the button type from `submit` to `button` also i added an `id for the button`. check it

Comment: Any reason to prefer jQuery over vanilla js ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

> Your code works as expected but as you have taken button type as `submit`, i submits the form.

```js
function val() {
  var x = document.getElementById('us').value
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="us" name="username"></input>
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```